# how can i track how many people filled out my website contact form?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

My website is all tagged up with Google Adwords and Analytics. The only thing left is to find how many people fill out a contact form. I mean i could individually count each email per month, but there must be an automated analytic way to do it yeah?

Is this something available on Adwords/Analytics? or do i need some manual code? Currently Google tracks the visit to /contact-us page, but nothing on the contact form itself

or is this maybe something that google wont handle but more specific to the provider of my contact form? i don't think i used any third party contact form. Pretty sure its just custom made one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking form submissions in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636823/tracking-form-submissions-in-google-analytics)

Comment: you can either 1) use Google Tag Manager and count number of times submit button is clicked 2) if you show a Thank you page after Submit button is clicked then you can count total sessions of Thank you page. 3) you can manually count total number of submissions from backend. (no need to count each email, just export report in csv format to get exact numbers) 4) you can also refer to above answer on Tracking form submissions. This should work.